# How to write a statistical mode analysis function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, optimization, statistics

I'm building a set of functions to deal with statistical analyses in PHP. This function deals with finding the mode or modes within an array. I can be a spaghetti artist at times as I'm just an enthusiast. I am looking for ways to make this cleaner or tighter, or use of any built-in functions that could be utilized that I'm not aware of. Thanks.

```
function mode( array $list )
{
    // mode - For lists, the mode is a most common (frequent) value. A list can have more than one mode. For histograms, a mode is a relative maximum ("bump").
    // this function can accept arrays of numbers and strings but not nested arrays.

    $arrayCountValues = array_count_values($list);
    arsort( $arrayCountValues );
    reset( $arrayCountValues );
    $firstKey = key( $arrayCountValues );

    $arrayCountValueDulpicates = array();
    $arrayCountValueDulpicatesListKeys = array();

    foreach ( $arrayCountValues as $key => $value )
    {
        if( $arrayCountValues[$firstKey] == $value )
        {
            $arrayCountValueDulpicates[] = $key;
//          echo 'key ' . $key . ' value ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    if( count( $arrayCountValueDulpicates ) != count( $list ) )
    {
        for ( $i=0; $i < count( $arrayCountValueDulpicates ) ; $i++ ) 
        { 
            $temp = array();
            foreach ($list as $key => $value) 
            {
                if ( $value == $arrayCountValueDulpicates[$i] ) 
                {
                    array_push( $temp, $key );
                    $arrayCountValueDulpicatesListKeys[$i] = $temp;
//                  echo 'key ' . $key . ' value ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }
        }

        $modes = array( 'modetype' => count( $arrayCountValueDulpicates ), 'modes' => $arrayCountValueDulpicates, 'observation' => count($arrayCountValueDulpicatesListKeys[0]), 'listkeys' => $arrayCountValueDulpicatesListKeys );

    }
    else
    {
        $modes = array( 'modetype' => 0, 'modes' => array(), 'observation' => 0, 'listkeys' => array() );
    }

    return $modes;
    // return array ( 'modetype' => 'integer number of modes', 'modes' => array( 'mode values' ), 'observation' => 'integer count of mode observed' , 'listkeys' => array( 'original lists keys that match mode values' ) );
}
```

Example data:

```
$numbers = array( 77, 32, 40, 100, 33, 98, 58, 63, 12, 35, 82, 61, 89, 70, 68, 24, 94, 73, 19, 18, 12, 35, 55, 96, 93, 37, 4, 77, 29, 47, 13, 63, 11, 84, 89, 6, 1, 63, 94, 36, 33, 1, 26, 18, 3, 41, 48, 99, 71, 37, 10, 69, 86, 46, 52, 53, 45, 49, 50, 97, 73, 18, 23, 39, 33, 53, 36, 52, 33, 31, 82, 43, 9, 11, 50, 46, 81, 35, 70, 77, 93, 50, 96, 42, 17, 40, 19, 45, 57, 36, 50, 20, 98, 96, 7, 80, 39, 30, 49, 24 );

$words = array( 'bake' => 'memorise', 'pets' => 'harmony', 'rampant' => 'capricious', 'rose' => 'hurry', 'shame' => 'craven', 'soak' => 'title', 'white' => 'shiver', 'example' => 'amusing', 'quarrelsome' => 'endurable', 'willing' => 'punish', 'neat' => 'coherent', 'tax' => 'learned', 'smooth' => 'title', 'boil' => 'aromatic', 'clumsy' => 'dolls', 'fear' => 'enter', 'zoom' => 'sleep', 'simple' => 'geese', 'turn' => 'title', 'pink' => 'whip', 'guiltless' => 'mice', 'thoughtless' => 'delicious', 'exotic' => 'oafish', 'capricious' => 'learned', 'action' => 'polish', 'show' => 'drum', 'choke' => 'title', 'encouraging' => 'brash', 'trust' => 'close', 'stimulating' => 'drum', 'ragged' => 'paper', 'dad' => 'line', 'careful' => 'spiteful', 'tedious' => 'history', 'bikes' => 'drum', 'shelter' => 'wrist', 'chalk' => 'hammer', 'grade' => 'part', 'anxious' => 'drum', 'nifty' => 'stem', 'appreciate' => 'attractive', 'crawl' => 'border', 'nest' => 'harmonious', 'mother' => 'abounding', 'quack' => 'spotty', 'undesirable' => 'crabby', 'tightfisted' => 'voice', 'supply' => 'acoustic', 'tick' => 'powder', 'expect' => 'need' );
```

Example useage

```
print_r(mode($numbers));

print_r(mode($words));
```

Function output:

```
Array
(
    [modetype] => 2
    [modes] => Array
        (
            [0] => 50
            [1] => 33
        )

    [observation] => 4
    [listkeys] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 58
                    [1] => 74
                    [2] => 81
                    [3] => 90
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 40
                    [2] => 64
                    [3] => 68
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [modetype] => 2
    [modes] => Array
        (
            [0] => drum
            [1] => title
        )

    [observation] => 4
    [listkeys] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => show
                    [1] => stimulating
                    [2] => bikes
                    [3] => anxious
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => soak
                    [1] => smooth
                    [2] => turn
                    [3] => choke
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Three lines of code.  Very likely to be faster than any hand-rolled code.  However, this gives you only one of the modes:

```
$a = array_count_values($numbers);
arsort($a);
echo key($a);   // 50

$a = array_count_values($words);
arsort($a);
echo key($a);   // 'drum'
```

Note:  As of PHP 7.3, this is a more logical thing for the last line:
    echo array_key_first($a);

To get multiple modes:

```
$a = array_count_values($words);
arsort($a);
$value = $a[key($a)];   // The value of the mode;  ('4' in this test)
// Now to find all the keys with that value
$keys = array();
foreach ($a as $k => $v)
{
    if ($v != $value)
        break;      // The sort lets us stop early
    $keys[] = $k;
}
print_r($keys);  // Array ( [0] => drum [1] => title )
```